# Finding probability of $P(|X-Y| ≤ 0.5)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

```
 f(x,y) = (x + y); 0 < x,y < 1
        = 0; otherwise
```

Find

```
    P(|X-Y| ≤ 0.5) = ?.
```

Comment: if it is given simply P(X-Y),then it is quiet easy to find,but i am finding difficulty when it is in mod,since we have to consider all four possibilities,can anyone provide any efficient one solution.

Comment: Hint: $P(|X-Y|\leq 0.5)=P(-0.5\leq X-Y\leq 0.5)$.

Comment: so,i have to calculate Finally as:P(X-Y ≤ 0.5) + P(X-Y ≥ -0.5) ??

Comment: No. $P(a\leq Z\leq b)=P(Z\leq b)-P(Z\leq a)$ for $Z$ having density and $a<b$.

Comment: The answer below assumes that the density of (X,Y) is **uniform** on the unit square--which is not the case that the exercise asks about. Why accept the answer?

Comment: Probably because the final answer was the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is clear from the comments, the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy $|X-Y|\leq 0.5$ are those between the lines $Y=X+0.5$ and $Y=X-0.5$.

Therefore the probability that you want to calculate should be calculated over the area inscribed between two lines $EH$ and $FG$ inside the square divided by the area of the big square. The easier way is to calculate the probability of the complementary area which is twice the probability calculated over $EDH$. You get:
$$
\Pr(|X-Y|\leq 0.5)=1-2\int_0^{\frac 12}\int_{\frac 12+x}^1(x+y)~dy~ dx=1-\frac 28=\frac{3}{4}.
$$

[image]

Comment: This assumes that the density of (X,Y) is uniform on the unit square--which is not the case that the exercise asks about.

Comment: You are right, thanks for noting that. Corrected.